# Stuck on trying to create a package.json for private organization repo

Tags: json, node.js, git, github

So here is some background information: I have a private organization repository and I have created separate repositories for each of my modules. I have a main repository which uses each of these modules.

The problem I am currently facing is I don't know how to add the modules to my package.json dependencies. Does anybody know how I would go about doing this?
I have tried googling but not much has helped me. Any help would make me so happy.

Comment: As in all cases `--save`. For example: `npm install https://github.com/foreverjs/forever --save`

Answer (score 0):

The `package.json`'s `dependencies` and `devDependencies` sections by default pull in dependencies from the public npm registry. When doing this, you only need to provide the version number (or semver expression) to pull in the dependency, e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "~4.0.0",
  "express-session": "~1.0.4"
}
```

To include a package from a non-public source, you can simply point it to the Git repo where your package is hosted:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-package": "git+https://mygitserver/git/myproject/myrepo.git#develop",
}
```

In the last bit of the URL, you can point it to a branch (e.g. `#develop` or `#master`), or to a tag (e.g. `#1.2.3`).